# Native C methods in Sedona - Level of Indirection

Tags: c, file, file-io

I'm working in a language called Sedona that can take native C methods. In order to integrate C in sedona, the variable declarations are a bit off.

1. Sedona -> C

   - bool  -> int32_t
   - bool[]    -> uint8_t*
   - byte  -> int32_t
   - byte[]    -> uint8_t*
   - short -> int32_t
   - short[]   -> uint16_t*
   - int   -> int32_t
   - int[] -> int32_t*
   - long  -> int64_t
   - long[]    -> int64_t*
   - float -> float
   - float[]   -> float*
   - double    -> double
   - double[]  -> double*
   - Obj   -> void*
   - Obj[] -> void**
   - Str   -> uint8_t*
   - Str[] -> uint8_t**

My method is trying to open a file, read its contents and return the contents of the file as a string for the other Sedona method to use. I know most of you probably don't know Sedona, but I am getting some errors that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sedona.h"

Cell MyWeblet_MainWeblet_getFile(SedonaVM* vm, Cell* params){
    uint8_t* file_name = params[1].aval;
    FILE *fp;
    uint8_t* fileContents;
    struct stat st;
    stat(&file_name, &st);
    int32_t size = st.st_size;
    int32_t itter = 0;
    Cell result;

    fileContents = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); //read mode

    if (fp==NULL){
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unit8_t* ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        fileContents[itter] = ch;
        itter++;

    }
    result.aval = fileContents;
    fclose(fp);
    return result;
}
```

I'm getting more errors than this, but here is an example of what pops up:

```
- warning C4047:'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'uint8_t **'
- warning C4024:'stat' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
- error C2275: 'int32_t' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

I really just want to understand what those errors mean, I don't need anyone to fix the code for me (although suggestions would be nice).

Comment: A few extra tips: you should make sure to check the return value of `stat()`, since it can fail for many reasons.  `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard, so there's no need to multiply by it.  You can replace the entire `while` loop with a single call to [`fread(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) (plus error checking).  You should also check to make sure that `malloc()` succeeds, and don't forget to `free()` it if another error occurs to avoid leaking (like if the file fails to open), although in this case you're exiting right away so that's not a big concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Difference in level of indirection** occurs when you assign a pointer variable to a non-pointer type, or more generally speaking when the number of indirections (stars) in the pointer variables differ. For example, you get this error in the following (de)referencing cases.

```
int *x, y;
x = y;  // correct use: x = &y;
y = x;  // correct use: y = *x;
```

In particular, the error you are getting shows a **mismatch between the formal and actual parameters**. This happens during a function call when the argument values that you pass on from a caller to a callee involves a difference in the indirection level. An example follows.

```
void swap(int* x, int *y) { ... }
int x = 2; y = 3;
swap(x, y);  // correct use: swap(&x, &y);
```

Unfortunately, C is not a strongly typed language and hence simply throws off warnings for these types of errors. C++ however, reports these as errors.

Comment: re *C is not strongly typed* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430182/is-c-strongly-typed

Answer (score 1):

In the line,

```
stat(&file_name, &st);
```

the argument `&file_name` is not appropriate. The type of the first argument to `stat` is `char const*`. The type of `&file_name` is `uint8_t**`.

If `char` and `uint8_t` are the same type in your platform, you can use:

```
stat(file_name, &st);
```