# Float value casted to char

Tags: c, casting

In the below code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char array[] = {'1', 2, 5.2};
  char* my_pointer = array[2];
  printf("%c", *my_pointer);
}
```

`5.2` is stored in IEEE 754 representation in memory, `char` picks 8 bits(first) from this float representation, due to little endian format.

C is a loosely typed language. Am allowed to cast `float` to `char`.

Why the program is core dumped?

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: Do things that are undefined behavior, expect undefined behavior to happen.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer  I know, how `5.2` is stored in memory, am picking 8 bits from it. Is that undefined? C is loosely typed language. I am allowed to cast `float` to `char`. Why should the executable core?

Comment: It shouldn't even compile the array definition. You shouldn't been able to use a double to init the array of char.

Comment: @Heisenbug Why it shouldn't compile? Because array is homogenuos data model?

Comment: @CherubimAnand That was a mistake from me. Program is working now.

Comment: Firstly, "char picks 8 bits(first) from this float representation, due to little endian format" - that does not make any sense. `5.2` will simply get converted to `char`, which does not have anything to do with endianness of the representation. Secondly, there's not a single `float` in your code. `5.2` is `double`, not `float`. Thirdly, `char* my_pointer = array[2];` is invalid C code.

Comment: @AnT What does it mean? when you say `5.2` will get converted to `char`? in memory?

Comment: @overexchange: It has nothing to do with memory representation. When you convert `5.2` to `char` type, the compiler will generate code that loads `5.2`, truncates the value and stores it in your `char` variable as `5`. In general case, it will happen in CPU/FPU, not "in memory".

Comment: @AnT I got your answer

Comment: Both `char` and `double` are arithmetic types. Conversion from one arithmetic type to another is defined in terms of values, not representations. The `double` value `5.2` is implicitly converted (not "cast") to type `char`, yielding the value `5`, or equivalently `'\x05` or `\005`. It's the character with the value `5`, often referred to (on most systems) as Control-E. Yes, you can convert a floating-point value to `char`, either explicitly (with a cast) or implicitly, and the result is well defined if the value is in range. It rarely makes sense to do so.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, there is no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is an explicit conversion operator, written as a type name in parentheses. A conversion can be explicit or implicit; an explicit conversion is called a "cast".

Comment: @KeithThompson  For your point: *Conversion from one arithmetic type to another is defined in terms of values, not representations*,  `char string[] = {1, 2, 3};` In this syntax, I see that conversion is in terms of representation.  Here binary representation of `1`(i.e., `0000 0001`)is stored in `string[0]`. Do you mean, `char` is not arithmetic type in C?

Comment: No, the behavior of arithmetic conversions is defined in terms of the numeric values, not their representations. Of course the value stored has a representation; that's not the point. The *value* `1`, which is of type `int`, is implicitly converted to `char`, yielding the same numeric value.

Comment: @KeithThompson You mean, if I say, `printf("%d", string[0])` would give same numeric value `1`?

Comment: You seem to be missing something, but I don't know what. Yes, `printf("%d", string[0])` will print the numeric value -- but that's because the `char` value of `string[0]` is *promoted* to `int`, because `printf` is a variadic function.

Comment: @KeithThompson For your point : *The value 1, which is of type `int`, is implicitly converted to `char`, yielding the same numeric value.*,  I did not get you, when you say, *yielding the same numeric value*. `string[0]` now has value `SOH` whose internal rep is `0000 0001`

Comment: Forget about representation. The *value* of `string[0]` is `1`. (When interpreted as an ASCII character, that happens to be SOH.)

Comment: @KeithThompson How do I retrieve the value of `string[0]`,  `1` in C code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125372/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-overexchange).

Answer (score 1):

In your program change `char *my_pointer = array[2];` to `char *my_pointer = &array[2];` as pointer should store the address.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  char array[] = {'1', 2, 45.2};
  char *my_pointer = &array[2];
  printf("%c", *my_pointer);
}
```

**output:**

```
- //NOTE: asci value of - is 45
```

as [**@AnT**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/ant) has mentioned in comments, when you convert `45.2` to `char` type, the compiler will generate code that loads `45.2`, truncates the value and stores it in your `char` variable as `45`, so when you print you get `-` as output.

Comment: Do you have any issues, if I have multiple data types in an array? As we say array is homogenous datamodel

Comment: to be honest @overexchange I don't know as I never usually use arrays that way. I stick to defined behaviour. You'd be better off asking others :)

Comment: "array is homogenous datamodel" what the heck does that mean? In C the array has the type you defined it with.

Comment: I think he meant that it stores collection of homogeneous type of data @WeatherVane

Comment: OP states that C is loosely typed. [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430182/is-c-strongly-typed). A `char[]` array stores... `char` values.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* my_pointer = array[2];
```

is wrong. The RHS of that is of type `char`, not a `char*`. Turning up the warning level in your compiler will help you identify problems like these.

With `gcc -Wall`, I get the following warning:

```
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:4:23: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
    char* my_pointer = array[2];
```

After that, the program has undefined behavior.

What you need is:

```
char* my_pointer = &array[2];
```

or

```
char* my_pointer = array + 2;
```