# How different is array from a pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays

In the below program,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a = 1025;
  int *p;
  p = &a;

  char *p0;
  p0 = (char *)p;


  //print("\n%d %d", *p0, *(p0+1));
  printf("\n%d and %d", *p0, p0[1]);

}
```

---

Output:

1 and 4

---

`char` & `int` are arithmetic types in C, To understand the output after type casting, I need to understand the binary representation of `1025`, which is, `00000000 00000000 00000100 00000001`. Little endianness of `Intel` arch will take first byte `00000001`.

Question:

For the above program written in java, array notation cannot be used to access each byte of `int`.

In the above C program, array notation can be alternatively used to access each byte of `int`.

As per this program, How different is array from a pointer in C?

Comment: An array is a contiguous sequence of elements.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  Same with one dimensional array in Java

Comment: https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_59.htm

Comment: There is no array in your program. `p[x]` is just shorthand for `*(p + x)`.

Comment: The difference is that in your example you are telling the compiler that `p0` is pointing to a sequence of *`char`* (or bytes). As far as I know, something like this is not possible in Java.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Oh ok, got u.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Another question, [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965300/float-value-casted-to-char#comment67210927_39965300) contradicts my point in the query, How do you see this?

Comment: @overexchange The comment you link describes casting of arithmetic values, not pointers.

Comment: "I need to understand the binary representation of 1025" The binary representation can as well be `00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000`.  And that's actually what you have, since you got the output `1 4`. This is because of CPU endianess.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck  hmm? `int p=1025; char ch = (char)1025;`. Am claiming that, to know value of  `ch`, I need to know the representation of `p`. Above program in query does indirectly using pointers. I know that any pointer type can be type casted to any other pointer type.

Comment: If you have `int p=1025;`, then the result of `char ch = (char)p;` doesn't depend on endianess. `ch` will get the least significant byte, so you get `ch == 1`.  However, `char ch = *((char*)&p);` will depend on endianess and `ch` will be either `1` or `0`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Correct!! You dont need to know endianness here, but I need to know the value sitting in the first byte of `int`(which is what I mean by representation).

Comment: @MichaelWalz What was the idea for C authors to introduce such shorthand notation, which is confusin for new learners?

Comment: @overexchange what confusion ? And tell me what is  more readable and what is easier to write: `p[x]` or `*(p + x)` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  `p[1]` is looks confusin, for a new learner mean, there is actual array in memory, where index 1 is being accessed from that array `p`. But `p` is not array of 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

*array* - a contiguous series of elements that actually exists in memory.  It *has an address*, usually considered as the address of the first element of the array.

*pointer* - a variable that *contains an address*.  The address contained in a pointer may or may not point to actual memory.

Think of it this way - your home *has an address*.  It exists *somewhere*, and you can put stuff in it - it's an *array*.  You can put any address on an envelope and try to mail it.  It may or may not get properly delivered for a lot of reasons - the street address written on an envelope is a *pointer*.  And you can't store anything in that writing.

Answer (score 0):

> For the above program written in java, array notation cannot be used to access each byte of int.

You're right

> In the above C program, array notation can be alternatively used to access each byte of int.

Yes, you can declare a `char` pointer, point it to the first byte of the `int` and then access each byte of the `int` variable with array notation.

The same way you can declare an array

```
char arr[3]={1,2,3};
```

And use it as a pointer

```
char *prt;
prt = arr;
```

That is equivalent to

```
ptr = & ( arr[0] ); // The address of the first element of arr
```

> As per this program, How different is array from a pointer in C?

To simplify (as per this program) an array is a pointer to the first element of the array.

`p0` is a pointer to an array whose items are `p0[0]`, `p0[1]`,...

**To clarify more:**

You can declare a variable as a pointer or as array.

In your code you don't declare arrays.

But as you use `p0[1]` you're treating `p0` as an array.

**Finally:**

I quote...

> To understand the output after type casting

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6752688/1579327

The result of casting a larger type into a smaller one is undefined (implementation dependent) iF the smaller type is signed and the value of the larger type doesn't fit into the smaller one.

Comment: What does it mean to say No? Can you share the java code? BTW, there is no array in the above query

Comment: I meant "array notation cannot be used to access each byte of int" (edited the answer)

Comment: What does *Yes* mean? Read what [Michael Walz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108113/how-different-is-array-from-a-pointer-in-c#comment67487671_40108113) says.

Comment: *Yes* means that what you stated is true. I tried to clarify more. See my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly answering the question in the title - **arrays are not pointers:**

---

- `int arr[10]`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `arr` and `&arr` are necessarily identical
  - `arr` points to a valid memory address, but cannot be set to point to any other memory address (i.e., it serves as a constant "label")

---

- `int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`:

  - Amount of memory used is `sizeof(int*) + sizeof(int)*10` bytes
  - The values of `ptr` and `&ptr` are not necessarily identical (in fact, they are mostly different)
  - `ptr` can be set to point to both valid and invalid memory addresses (i.e., you can change it during runtime as many times as you will)

Comment: By "values", I mean, if you cast them to `void*` or to `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though they aren't the same thing, there *is* a close relationship between arrays and pointers in C.  The array subscripting operation `a[i]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic:

```
a[i] == *(a + i)
```

That is, take the *address* `a`, offset `i` *elements* of the array's base type from that address, and dereference the result.  For example, if `a` is an array of `int`, the expression `a + 1` evaluates to the address of the next *integer object* following the one stored at `a`, which may be anywhere from 2, 4, or 8 bytes away.

Arrays are not pointers; however, except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a *string literal* being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

So, given the code

```
int a[10];
a[2] = 2;
```

In the statement `a[2] = 2`, the *expression* `a` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it is converted ("decays") from type `int [10]` to `int *`, and it evaluates to the address of the first element of `a`.  We then offset 2 elements of type `int` from that address and assign the value 2 to that location.  Note that this conversion applies to the *expression* `a`, not the array object to which it refers.

So how does all that relate to your code?

In C, a non-bitfield object is composed of a contiguous sequence of one or more bytes.  Objects of `char` type take up 1 byte by definition, so an object of any multibyte type (`int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, etc.) can be treated as an array of `char` (or `unsigned char`).

A picture may help - I took your code and used a little utility I wrote to dump the contents of each object in memory:

```
       Item        Address   00   01   02   03
       ----        -------   --   --   --   --
          a 0x7ffffa8a29cc   01   04   00   00    ....

          p 0x7ffffa8a29c0   cc   29   8a   fa    .)..
            0x7ffffa8a29c4   ff   7f   00   00    ....

         p0 0x7ffffa8a29b8   cc   29   8a   fa    .)..
            0x7ffffa8a29bc   ff   7f   00   00    ....
```

The binary representation of `1025` is `0x0401`.  As you can see, the object `a` is 4 bytes wide and contains the byte sequence `{0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00}`.  This is on an x86 system, which is little-endian, so the *least* significant byte comes first in the sequence.

Both `p` and `p0` store the address of `a`.  I'm on a 64-bit system, so pointer values are 8 bytes wide.

`*p0` evaluates to the value of first byte in `a`, which in this case is `0x01`.  `p0[1]` is equivalent to `*(p0 + 1)`, and evaluates to the value of the second character value following `p0`, which in this case is `0x04`.