# What is the state of Ruby as a compiled language?

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction

Ruby has been around for a while now so I was wondering if there was any work being done on a compiler for it? I know that compiler design is hindered by things like Eval() so I would not expect implementations to be 100 percent accurate? My own searches have turned up sparse results.

Comment: A bad compiler will create programs that are just as slow as a bad JITer - this is not something people should be putting effort into.

Comment: @Unicorn ~ Even a bad compiler works a basic obfuscator. There are many reasons someone could want to build a compiler besides just speed of execution, like pure academics, and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org) offers Ahead-of-Time Compilation as of v0.5. It uses LLVM to compile binaries that will run on the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: I'm running on windows but of the two non-preferred platform responses I like OSX more.

Answer (score 0):

[Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) is a JIT compiler for Ruby.  A pure compiler will never exist for Ruby because the language is far too dynamic for a static compiler to work.  Whatever it did internally would be incredibly ugly and would evolve towards a JIT as they tried to optimize it anyway.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with Ruby.  Is it really so much more dynamic than Common Lisp, which is normally compiled?

Comment: Here is a good walk though of some of the ideas about what is or is not a compiled language. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376611/why-interpreted-langs-are-mostly-ducktyped-while-compiled-have-strong-typing/376828#376828

Answer (score 0):

There's Mirah, for compiling Ruby code into Java bytecode:

http://www.mirah.org/

I believe you could obfuscate your code this way.